# Questions about meta box: nonce and parameters available

Tags: plugin-development

1st question is: is a nonce required for a meta box? i read on the wordpress codex [`add_meta_box`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box) and they have a nonce for the meta box, i'd thought that maybe the add post form will already include a nonce?

```
echo '<input type="hidden" name="myplugin_noncename" id="myplugin_noncename" value="' . wp_create_nonce( plugin_basename(__FILE__) ) . '" />';
```

2nd question is: whats the parameters available for the function that creates the markup of the meta box. from what i read in profesional wordpress looks like

```
function pp_meta($post, $box)
```

how will i know what parameters are available in such functions? and what does `box` refer to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about nonces.

As for arguments it is probably their usage of [add_meta_box()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box):

> **$callback_args** 
>   *(array) (optional)* Arguments to pass into your callback function. The callback will receive the $post object and whatever parameters are passed through this variable. 
>   Default: null

So `$post` is post object and `$box` is whatever they are passing in `$callback_args`

Comment: The nonce in the example is unrelated to add_meta_box. It's just something that example code is making use of to use it to protect the form, but that's optional. You can learn more about nonces here: wp_create_nonce() : http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_create_nonce